# Will docker inherit the host kernel parameters, such as tcp_tw_reuse/tcp_fin_timeout?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

I am confused with whether docker will inherit the host's kernel parameter.I have do some tests as below:
The kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
```

1. I want to echo the `ip_local_port_range` parm and the command is :

```
$ sudo docker run --rm busybox cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

the output:

```
128
```

That is quite reasonable as `ip_local_port_range` is a namespaced parameter and I guess it inherits from the host.

2. Test `tcp_tw_reuse` parameter:

```
sudo docker run --rm busybox cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

the output:

```
cat: can't open '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse': No such file or directory
```

That is reasonable too, as far as I know, in kernel 3.10 the tcp_tw_reuse is not namespaced and the docker does not have that file.
Now, I would like to know is, as the '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse' file is not present in the container, will the container inherit its value from the host. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vanilla 3.10 kernel was released in 2013. Namespacing of `tcp_fin_timeout` happened [much later](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1e579caa18b96f9eb18f4f5416658cd15f37c062), in early 2016, and namespacing of `tcp_tw_reuse` happened [even later](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/56ab6b93007e5000a8812985aec1833c4a6a9ce0).

In fact, [these](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8bb495e3f02401ee6f76d1b1d77f3ac9f079e376/include/net/netns/ipv4.h#L58-L68) are the networking sysctls which are namespaced in vanilla 3.10:

```
int sysctl_icmp_echo_ignore_all;
int sysctl_icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts;
int sysctl_icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses;
int sysctl_icmp_ratelimit;
int sysctl_icmp_ratemask;
int sysctl_icmp_errors_use_inbound_ifaddr;

int sysctl_tcp_ecn;

kgid_t sysctl_ping_group_range[2];
long sysctl_tcp_mem[3];
```

Not so much. Other sysctls are globals, used disregarding what the caller's network namespace is. This includes sysctls of your interest:

- `tcp_fin_timeout` - [definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8bb495e3f02401ee6f76d1b1d77f3ac9f079e376/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L283), [use](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8bb495e3f02401ee6f76d1b1d77f3ac9f079e376/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L2557);
- `tcp_tw_reuse` - [definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8bb495e3f02401ee6f76d1b1d77f3ac9f079e376/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L88), [use](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8bb495e3f02401ee6f76d1b1d77f3ac9f079e376/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L126).

Note, that latest RHEL/CentOS versions of kernel 3.10 (which you seem to use) have some more sysctls namespaced - e.g. `ip_local_port_range`, mentioned by you, but this still does not include `tcp_fin_timeout` and `tcp_tw_reuse`.

So, finally answering your question: in kernel 3.10, these parameters are system-wide, and containerized processes use the same values of these sysctls as the host system.

Comment: Awesome !!! So grateful for your help and now I only need to change that `sysctls` on the host system. I will do more tests and thanks again!